# OpenCV + python -- grab frames from a video file

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I can't seem to capture frames from a file using OpenCV -- I've compiled from source on Ubuntu with all the necessary prereqs according to:  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide%20%3A%20Debian

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv
import sys

files = sys.argv[1:]

for f in files:
    capture = cv.CaptureFromFile(f)
    print capture

    print cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    print cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

    for i in xrange(10000):
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        if frame:
            print frame
```

Output:

```
ubuntu@local:~/opencv$ ./test.py bbb.avi 
<Capture 0xa37b130>
0.0
0.0
```

The frames are always None...

I've transcoded a video file to i420 format using:

```
mencoder $1 -nosound -ovc raw -vf format=i420 -o $2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. This worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 10.04 using Opencv's 2.1 packages. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You don't have the `gstreamer-ffmpeg` or `gsteamer-python` or `gsteamer-python-devel` packages installed. I installed all three of them. and the exact same problem was resolved.

Comment: It's a typo, but those who are copy/pasting, make sure you actually get "gstreamer-python" and "gstreamer-python-devel". Don't forget the R.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using OpenCV 2.2.0, compiled on Ubuntu from source.  I can confirm that the source code you provided works as expected.  So the problem is somewhere else.

I couldn't reproduce your problem using mencoder (installing it is a bit of a problem on my machine) so I used `ffmpeg` to wrap a raw video in the AVI container:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -i ~/local/sample-video/foreman.yuv -vcodec copy foreman.avi
```

(foreman.yuv is a standard CIF image sequence you can find on the net if you [look around](http://www.cipr.rpi.edu/resource/sequences/sif.html)).

Running the AVI from `ffmpeg` through your source gives this:

```
misha@misha-desktop:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python ocv_video.py foreman.avi
<Capture 0xa71120>
352.0
288.0
<iplimage(nChannels=3 width=352 height=288 widthStep=1056 )>
<iplimage(nChannels=3 width=352 height=288 widthStep=1056 )>
...
```

So things work as expected.  What you should check:

- Do you get any errors on standard output/standard error?  OpenCV uses `ffmpeg` libraries to read video files, so be on the lookout for informative messages.  Here's what happens if you try to play a RAW video file without a container (sounds similar to your problem):

error:

```
misha@misha-desktop:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python ocv_video.py foreman.yuv 
[IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff37c8d040] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff37c8cf20] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[rawvideo @ 0x19e65c0] Could not find codec parameters (Video: rawvideo, yuv420p)
[rawvideo @ 0x19e65c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module decodebin20 reported: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
<Capture 0x19e3130>
0.0
0.0
```

- Make sure your AVI file actually contains the required information to play back the video.  At a minimum, this should be the frame dimensions.  RAW video typically doesn't contain any information besides the actual pixel data, so knowing the frame dimensions and FPS is required.  You can wrong-guess the FPS and still get a viewable video, but if you get the dimensions wrong, the video will be unviewable.
- Make sure the AVI file you're trying to open is actually playable.  Try `ffplay file.avi` -- if that fails, then the problem is likely to be with the file.  Try using `ffmpeg` to transcode instead of `mencoder`.
- Make sure you can play other videos, using the same method as above.  If you can't, then it's likely that your `ffmpeg` install is broken.

Comment: Thanks misha, I'll give these ideas a try -- no errors from ffmpeg as far as I can tell...  One question, have you used any different packages when you installed all the dependencies from what they have on their wiki?